# concat dataframes based on dates multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, concatenation

I have two dataframes:

dataframe 1:

```
>>>date         ex_1
0 2019-12-06    0.312
1 2019-12-11    0.521
2 2019-12-31    0.305
...
```

and dataframe 2:

```
>>>date         ex_2
0  2019-12-06     0.228
1  2019-12-11     0.433
2  2019-12-16     0.143
```

I would like to concat the two tables based on the date, so if there is overlap date, the row will contain the values for each experiment on the same row, and if there is only one day it will add it and give null to the column that has no value.

I have tried to do this based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774014/join-two-dataframes-based-on-different-dates) answer :

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('date'), ndf2.set_index('date')]).sort_index(ascending=True)
```

and it indeed concat but the problem is that if the date appeas in two tables it duplicates:

```
date             ex1        ex2
2019-12-06      0.312      Nan
2019-12-06      Nan        0.228
2019-12-11      0.521      Nan
2019-12-11      NaN        0.433
2019-12-16      NaN        0.143
2019-12-31      0.305      NaN
```

**My desired output should look like this:**

```
date             ex1        ex2
2019-12-06      0.312      0.228
2019-12-11      0.521      0.433
2019-12-16      NaN        0.143
2019-12-31      0.305      NaN
```

Comment: Use: `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')`

Comment: `concat(..., axis=1)` but `merge` is a better solution here.